# Dependency Injection From class Library

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I am using .Net core 2.0 and implemented Constructor Dependency Injection (DI). Everything working as expected with controller constructor.

For example, If In the class library I want to create an object how can I call it without using constructor.

```
public interface IAppConfig
{
     string Test();

}

public class AppConfig : IAppConfig
{
    public AppConfig(IConfiguration configuration)
    {

    }

    public string Test()
    {
        return "Done";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Even if you use an IoC container, it will also call the constructor after the dependency tree is resolved. Any object is created by an explicit or implicit call to the constructor.